# Table on smaller screen to appear as list with several columns collapsed and shown on accordion

Tags: html, css, html-table, bootstrap-4

I have a table in bootstrap as follows:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>LastName</th>
  <th>Color</th>
   <th>Car</th>
  <th>Year</th>
  <th>Price</th>

 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
<tr>
  <td>01/02/2017</td>
  <td>Dan</td>
  <td>Green</td>  
  <td>Blue</td>
  <td>BMW</td>
  <td>2016</td>  
  <td>100k</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
  <td>01/02/2017</td>
  <td>Dan</td>
  <td>Green</td>  
  <td>Blue</td>
  <td>BMW</td>
  <td>2016</td>  
  <td>100k</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
  <td>01/02/2017</td>
  <td>Dan</td>
  <td>Green</td>  
  <td>Blue</td>
  <td>BMW</td>
  <td>2016</td>  
  <td>100k</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
  <td>01/02/2017</td>
  <td>Dan</td>
  <td>Green</td>  
  <td>Blue</td>
  <td>BMW</td>
  <td>2016</td>  
  <td>100k</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
  <td>01/02/2017</td>
  <td>Dan</td>
  <td>Green</td>  
  <td>Blue</td>
  <td>BMW</td>
  <td>2016</td>  
  <td>100k</td>
</tr>

 </tbody>
 </table>
```

What I want to do is that on a breakpoint, say a screen smaller than 768px, to display the table like this :

```
DATE:01/05/2017
car:BMW
```

And then on click on this row to display:

```
 Name:Dan
 LastName:Green
 Color:blue
 Year:2016
```

Is there a way to achieve this with bootstrap?
Or maybe I shouldn't have everything in a table and instead have elements in a list, and make them display as table (cells) and on smaller screens to align them?
Because at first I thought of creating two views and display/hide them according to the screen size, because I dont know how to do it this way. 
I'm a beginner so I apologize in advance.
I don't know which are best practices and how to achieve this, preferably using css only. Whereas JS only on click to hide and show that part.

Here is a js fiddle [Bootstrap Table](http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/323/)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Better show what you've tried so far, then people can help you from that point onwards

Answer (score 0):

For the layout you should have a look at the bootstrap grid. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

It does not technically use "table" but divs and you set how many columns you want a div to take for each screen size. When I started with bootstap I watched though this nice youtube tutorial that explained it well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3LRU3JF-rQ